# Restrict sudo -i or sudo -s commands from sudoers file

Tags: linux, debian, sudoers

Is there a way to restrict the following commands `sudo -i` or `sudo -s` in the `sudoers` file?

When I add `!/usr/bin/sudo -i` or `!/usr/bin/sudo -s`, `sudo` still allows users to run the command.

Comment: And what about `sudo /bin/bash` or `sudo /bin/zsh` or `sudo /some/renamed/bash`? If you want to restrict users, you *have to* whitelist allowed commands.

Comment: Are you saying that I should whitelist instead of having a blacklist?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not a good answer, as I can't directly reply to your question, but in `man sudoers` there's a section called *Preventing Shell Escapes* which I think may be of interest to you:

> Once sudo executes a program, that program is free to do whatever it
>          pleases, including run other programs.  This can be a security issue
>          since it is not uncommon for a program to allow shell escapes, which
>          lets a user bypass sudo's access control and logging.  Common programs
>          that permit shell escapes include shells (obviously), editors,
>          paginators, mail and terminal programs.
>
> There are two basic approaches to this problem:
>
> ```
>    restrict  Avoid giving users access to commands that allow the user to
>              run arbitrary commands.  Many editors have a restricted mode
>              where shell escapes are disabled, though sudoedit is a better
>              solution to running editors via sudo.  Due to the large
>              number of programs that offer shell escapes, restricting
>              users to the set of programs that do not is often unworkable.
>
>    noexec    Many systems that support shared libraries have the ability
>              to override default library functions by pointing an
>              environment variable (usually LD_PRELOAD) to an alternate
>              shared library.  On such systems, sudo's noexec functionality
>              can be used to prevent a program run by sudo from executing
>              any other programs.  Note, however, that this applies only to
>              native dynamically-linked executables.  Statically-linked
>              executables and foreign executables running under binary
>              emulation are not affected.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

A blacklist in sudoers is almost certainly a waste of time. There are just too many workarounds.

For implementing any sort of restrictions a whitelist is the only practical approach. Even then be careful of permissions on any commands included in the whitelist (regular auditing of this will be required), any commands that may allow shell escapes, and any commands that can write new/existing files.

So, for example, these are bad ideas:

- allowing sudo access to execute a script owned by the user
- giving sudo access to "less"
- giving sudo access to "cp"